# Filtering questions by bounty in iOS app

Tags: support, bounties, sorting, ios-app

How can I find questions with a bounty in the iOS app? (and sort by highest bounty and newest questions)

Comment: You can't. Make this a feature request and you've got my upvote

Answer (score 2):

I don't know when it was added, but sorting by bounty is currently available in version 1.6.4.

On the **Questions** page, you can change the sort by tapping the searchbtype on the top left. Next tap the **Filter** option and select **With Bounty**.

[image: Filter by bounty on iPhone]