# Is it possible to view Featured Question via the mobile site and iOS/android app?

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties, android-app, ios-app

On the mobile site and iOS/android app, I'm unable to find how to view featured questions for particular tags. I can see the choice for Active, Newest, Votes etc, but Featured isn't in the list. Would it be possible to add this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when it was added, but the iOS app *does* have a feature for filtering by questions with bounties.

From *[Filtering questions by bounty in iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231431/351462)*

> On the **Questions** page, you can change the sort by tapping the search
>   type on the top left. Next tap the **Filter** option and select **With Bounty**.
>
> [image: Filter by bounty on iPhone]